# Form with jquery no want works

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms

I try one time and other and no get finally get works this form with jquery and json :

```
<script>
var idcc="<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>";
</script>


<script>
$('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).on('submit',function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $phpValidate;?>',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : $('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
            alert('all done');
        }
    });
});
</script>


<form id="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>" class="contact-form-widget" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="contact_text">
    <input class="contact_rapid_boton" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The problem it´s when i push over the buttom always go to other page , no stay and works , don´t know what bad because i see all right but sure something no works right at all

Comment: You forgot document ready !

Comment: and to prevent the default action

Comment: Did you include the jquery framework? Try to have an alert box.

Comment: yes i do and all time reload other page , the page for verification

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery, use a DOM ready handler, and prevent the form from submitting and reloading the page :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var idcc = "<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>";
    $(function() {
        $('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url  : '<?php echo $phpValidate;?>',
                type : 'POST',
                data : $('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).serialize(),
                success: function(json) {
                    alert('all done');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="contact-form-widget-<?php echo $tfw_number_format;?>" class="contact-form-widget" method="post" action=""></form>
```

Comment: Continue send me other page for verification , reaload all time and no work me ..... :(

Comment: It should be working fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/Zevd4/ , so that means you're probably echoing something invalid from PHP, which is impossible for me to test ?

Answer (score 0):

use `event.preventDefault()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).on('submit',function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $phpValidate;?>',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : $('#contact-form-widget-'+idcc).serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
            alert('all done');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```